# Bootstrap 5 Popover Error - Cannot find name 'bootstrap'

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to create a popover in the Javascript of my Angular 12 project. I am using Boostrap `v5.0.1`. I can't seem to get rid of a name error when I am trying to create the popover:

```
 var exampleEl = document.getElementById(item.name + index);
 var tooltip = new bootstrap.Popover(exampleEl, {
    container: 'body',
    animation: true
 });
```

Typescript is telling me `"Can't find name bootstrap"`.

I have added bootrap.js to my angular.json file:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

According to the docs, popper.js is included in the bundle file. I am not using jQuery and do not want to include it. I have not seen another post with a similar issue so I must be just overlooking something small. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Posting this declaration at the top of the file worked:

```
declare var bootstrap: any;
```

Comment: I was experimenting with a bootstrap menu inside an angular component, and had this same error.  adding this code under the import fixed it.

Comment: Same for me @greg. Is there anything else to consider with this solution?